# running command with sudo gives different result

Tags: debian, shell, nagios, user-accounts, user-permissions

I'm connected with root via ssh on a debian squeeze server. If I execute the command:

```
 /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_procs -w 1:1 -c 1:1 -a '/usr/local/freeswitch/bin/freeswitch'
```

I get the result:

```
PROCS OK: 1 process with args '/usr/local/freeswitch/bin/freeswitch'
```

If I execute:

```
sudo /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_procs -w 1:1 -c 1:1 -a '/usr/local/freeswitch/bin/freeswitch'
```

I get:

```
PROCS CRITICAL: 2 processes with args '/usr/local/freeswitch/bin/freeswitch'
```

Here my /etc/sudoers:

```
Defaults    env_reset
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
nagios      ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/
```

However sudo also executes the command as root I get another result. How can that be? On an other machine with debian lenny I do not have the problem, both commands give the same result.

Comment: Is the second output correct ?

Comment: and what is the output when running this plugin as `nagios` user?

Comment: I got the 'PROCS CRITICAL' command when running as nagios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are seeing is a result of the amount of the command line being returned by the underlying 'ps' command that is used by check_procs.

In the case of the sudo blah...blah, it is possible that the entire command sudo blah....blah is displayed as one process as well as simply the one with just blah.

This is similar why when you pipeline commands such as grep, one generally has to include a command to get rid of the grep command itself.

For Example:

```
     ps -aef | grep -v grep | grep xinetd
```

Comment: OK, know I understand the problem. I opened another question to understand why the bahaviour is different on different servers: http://serverfault.com/questions/324557/sudo-process-in-process-list.

Comment: It's equally efficient to do something like: `ps -aef | grep [x]inetd` The square brackets around the x indicate 'match the character class that only has an x' so /[x]inetd/ match "xinetd" but not "[x]inetd".