# sudo process in process list

Tags: debian, shell

I've a different behaviour for the same command on 2 different machines:

Server 1:

sudo /bin/ps -AF | grep sudo

```
root 19370 14291 0 1809 828 3 11:12 pts/1 00:00:00 grep sudo
```

Server 2:

sudo ps -AF | grep sudo

```
root 17706 12645 0 5604 1228 2 11:13 pts/0 00:00:00 sudo ps -AF 
root 17707 12645 0 2402 896 1 11:13 pts/0 00:00:00 grep sudo
```

Sever 2 displays the sudo process, Server 1 not. How can that be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the `ps` version and which distro you are using, `ps` command may doesn't show itself in the listing.

CentOS, procps version 3.2.7:

```
$ sudo /bin/ps -AF | grep sudo
quanta   19175 14068  0 15302   740   7 17:04 pts/1    00:00:00 grep sudo
```

Gentoo, procps version 3.2.8:

```
$ sudo /bin/ps -AF | grep sudo
root      4842  4783  0  1512  1468   0 16:54 pts/10   00:00:00 sudo /bin/ps -AF
quanta    4843  4783  0  1059   844   1 16:54 pts/10   00:00:00 grep --colour=auto sudo
```

Comment: ok, my servers differ in the debian version. Server 1 runs lenny and Server 2 squeeze. Do you know if there is a difference? Is there a parameter to change the behaviour?

Comment: Run `ps -V` to check the version. What is your final goal? AFAIK, there is no option to change this behaviour. But you can download the `procps` source code to compile.